# How to create method that can receive a parameter of both: byte[] and Byte[] without Overloading Methods

Tags: java, methods

which can be called: `method(new byte[5])` and `method(new Byte[5])`

e.g. i have in my code:

```
Byte[] array = list.toArray(new Byte[list.size()]);
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
```

and to work with both arrays i forced to duplicate each method separately for `byte[]` and `Byte[]`

Maybe it can be done with generic types or somehow else?

Comment: Don't do this, please. `byte[]` is separate from 'Byte[]` by quite a bit. You could accept an `Object`, then cast. Why would you do this though?

Comment: Java supports **Overloading** methods, check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: You can't have a single method that accepts either `byte[]` or `Byte[]`, but nothing else. They are not the same type. You might as well ask for a method that can accept a `List` and a `double`. To Java, they are no more or less different than `byte[]` vs `Byte[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receive `Object` as parameter and check whether it is instance of `Byte[]` or `byte[]` and then cast it.

```
public void method(Object object){
        if(object instanceof byte[]){ //check if object is of type byte[]
            byte[] bytes=(byte[]) object;//cast it as byte[]
            //work with byte[]
        }
        else if(object instanceof Byte[]){
            Byte[] bytes=(Byte[]) object;
            //work with Byte[]
        }
        else{
            //the object is neither byte[] or Byte[]
        }
    }
```

> This however is a very bad practice. If your task doesn't state directly to use the same method for both cases use method overloading.

Comment: Awful answer. It recommends completely abandoning object-oriented or type-oriented programming and creating instead brittle, unmaintainable hacks. This does not help anyone become a better programmer. Not only that, the OP _still_ has to code for both types separately, only now with a messy if-chain, harder-to-find logic, and extra boiler plate. This doesn't begin to solve their stated problem.

Comment: Agreed, this is a bad solution. You need to overload the methods, allowing the method to accept `Object` type is dangerous practice.

Comment: Moreover, it is always best to discover errors at compile time, rather than run time where possible.  The `Object` method will accept any type, even types not remotely related to Byte or byte.  With overloaded methods, the code wouldn't compile if a call with an unsupported type was made, but with this method who knows how remotely from the method call a `ClassCastException` would be thrown, if at all ... the worst outcome is that this method would just silently do the wrong thing.

Comment: This is indeed a bad practice but responds to the OP's question which states directly that he does not want to use method overloading.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [Method Overloading](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/). This is the correct way to do what you're trying to achieve. Without using overloading you are violating OOP principles and your code will be less reliable, and messier.

You can create multiple methods with the same name, so long as their parameters are separate.

```
public void methodName(byte[] array) {
...
}

public void methodName(Byte[] array) {
...
}
```

Now when you call, it will automatically use the correct version based on whatever you're passing.

```
// Both of these work fine.
methodName(new byte[8]);
methodName(new Byte[8]);

// This does not work. Compiler error.
methodName("pass a string");
```

Comment: but if i have many methods, i must duplicate same code for each one

Comment: @АлександрКиберман You don't duplicate the exact same code. The point of overloading is that you usually need to handle different types in a slightly different way. If you truly repeat the same code, you can create a master method that only has it once, and each overloaded method will call it with the correct type. You can only abstract out code that is independent of your overloaded type though.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things:

1. If your method code behavior differs for a byte[] and Byte[] then you should either create different methods for 2 purpose or can take Object as a parameter. I would suggest creating different methods.
2. You will not be able to make the same method used for 2 different types of array. If there is a flexibility and you can use ArrayList then it can be done. The only thing is once control is inside the method you will loose the information whether the value was passed as a byte primitive or a Byte wrapper.

Example code:

```
public class ByteExample {

    public static void methodAcceptingBothBytes(List<Byte> bytes){
        for(Byte byteVal: bytes){
            System.out.println(byteVal);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a=100;
        ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
        bytes.add(a);
        bytes.add(new Byte("10"));
        methodAcceptingBothBytes(bytes);

    }
}
```